# Why would oracle subquery with AND & OR return returning wrogn results set

Tags: oracle11g

I have two subqueries. as shown below. the first query works fine  but the second query which is basically the first query that I modified to use AND & OR, doesn't work in the sense that it doesn't return ID as expected. any suggestions on what is happening here?

```
    1. (SELECT * FROM (SELECT  EMPID FROM EVENT_F 
                    INNER JOIN WCINFORMATION_D 
                          ON EVENT_F.JOB_INFO_ROW_WID=  WCINFORMATION_D.ROW_WID
                          INNER JOIN WCANDIDATE_D ON WCCANDIDATE_D.ROW_WID = VENT_F.CANDIDATE_ROW_WID

                WHERE STEP_NAME = 'Offer'
               AND  WCINFORMATION_D.JOB_FAMILY_NAME  IN ('MDP','ELP','Emerging Leader Program','Other')
               AND TITLE  NOT IN ('Student Ambassador Program for Eligible Summer Interns','Student Ambassador')

                  AND  PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = OUTERAPP.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
                  --limit 1


                  ORDER BY CREATION_DT ASC
                  ) T1 WHERE ROWNUM=1) AS A_ID,
2.(SELECT * FROM (SELECT  EMPID FROM EVENT_F 
                    INNER JOIN WCINFORMATION_D 
                          ON EVENT_F.JOB_INFO_ROW_WID=  WCINFORMATION_D.ROW_WID
                          INNER JOIN WCANDIDATE_D ON WCCANDIDATE_D.ROW_WID = VENT_F.CANDIDATE_ROW_WID

                WHERE STEP_NAME = 'Offer'
               AND  WCINFORMATION_D.JOB_FAMILY_NAME  IN ('MDP','ELP','Emerging Leader Program','Other') or WCINFORMATION_D.JOB_FAMILY_NAME   NOT IN ('MDP','ELP','Emerging Leader Program','Other')
               AND TITLE  NOT IN ('Student Ambassador Program for Eligible Summer Interns','Student Ambassador')

                  AND  PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = OUTERAPP.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
                  --limit 1


                  ORDER BY CREATION_DT ASC
                  ) T1 WHERE ROWNUM=1) AS A_ID,
```

Comment: you could at least format the  code

Comment: Probably missing begin and end parentheses --> (X) AND ( (A) OR (B) )

Comment: I had formatted sorry it seems the format didn't work the way I thought it would. if you meant to have parentheses like here AND  WCINFORMATION_D.JOB_FAMILY_NAME  IN (('MDP','ELP','Emerging Leader Program','Other') or WCINFORMATION_D.JOB_FAMILY_NAME   NOT IN ('MDP','ELP','Emerging Leader Program','Other'))
             : it doesn't work either.

Comment: Those parentheses aren't right; but it isn't clear what you are trying to do. You have the same list of value for the `IN` and `NOT IN`, so it you just `OR` those two together to get everything (except nulls). So what should the logic be?

Comment: I wanted to get a count of  all the people we hired that were In the Job family named (MDP and ELP) and all the people that we hired that we not part of MDP or ELP

Comment: I added parentheses like shown here  AND  (WCINFORMATION_D.JOB_FAMILY_NAME  IN ('MDP','ELP','Emerging Leader Program','Other') or WCINFORMATION_D.JOB_FAMILY_NAME   NOT IN ('MDP','ELP','Emerging Leader Program','Other'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to get the count of people in one set of job families, plus a count of people in another set, you need to use a conditional count, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN wid.job_family_name IN ('MDP', 'ELP', 'Emerging Leader Program', 'Other') THEN 1 END) job_family_grp1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN wid.job_family_name IS NULL OR wid.job_family_name NOT IN ('MDP', 'ELP', 'Emerging Leader Program', 'Other') THEN 1 END) job_family_grp2
FROM   event_f ef
INNER  JOIN wcinformation_d wid
ON     ef.job_info_row_wid = wid.row_wid
INNER  JOIN wcandidate_d wcd
ON     wcd.row_wid = ef.candidate_row_wid
WHERE  step_name = 'Offer' -- alias this column name
AND    title NOT IN ('Student Ambassador Program for Eligible Summer Interns', 'Student Ambassador') -- alias this column name;
```

You will most likely need to amend this to work for your particular case (it'll have to go as a join into your main query, given there are two columns being selected) since you didn't provide enough information in your question to give us the wider context.

Comment: Sorry I am trying first to extract the employee ID then get a count by modifying the query. so first thing is to make sure I get correct employee id's returned

Comment: Thanks, although this was not the correct answer, it pointed me to the correct way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Just fyi, if you had provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we could have helped provide a much more tailored answer to your question. I'm glad you were able to solve your problem in the end, though.